# I regularized my linear regression, now what?

Tags: regression, lasso, regularization

I have estimated the regression parameters of a linear regression models using LASSO, sent some variables to zero using cross validation, and now I got a final model. It is known that regularizing induces bias on the active variables, but it is a good price to pay for getting rid of spurious variables. What do I do now that I have got my final model with only a fifth of the original variables? Should I just deal with the bias on the remaining variables like a champ or is there a clever way to proceed?

Comment: Love the no nonsense attitude in your question :) Keep it up!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One common approach is to now redo the regression (without regularization) using only the variables that were selected by LASSO.

This is called "post-selection inference." See [Lee et al. 2016](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.6238.pdf) for finding p-values and confidence intervals on the resulting estimates.

Answer (score 1):

You may ask yourself, what is the goal of building this model. Are you trying to get a better prediction performance? Or you want a linear model that statistically significant. These two goals are not necessarily aligned.

From machine learning perspective, you always want to know you are overfitting or under-fitting. If you already under fitting, regularization will make it worse.